# Install profile installation fails with "Base table or [error] view not found: 1146 Table 'xxx.system' doesn't exist'" on aegir

Tags: 7, aegir, installation-profiles

I tried to install a custom installation profile on aegir today, the installation failed with this message:

```
Exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or 
view not found: 1146 Table 'xxx.system' doesn't exist'
```

A local installation in a vagrant via drush worked without Problems.

Answer (score 0):

The reason for this obscure error message was that I had defined a dependency in the installation profile, but the module was missing. After removing the not-existing module from the profile.info-file the installation went smooth.